# Displaying a double in a label that contains time makes the position jumpy

Tags: sprite-kit

I couldn't think of a better way to title this, so hopefully the description helps.

I have a game in which the elapsed time is displayed at the top. As the time changes, different numbers have different physical sizes, so the physical length of the label changes very slightly for each fraction of a second. This makes it so the whole number doesn't appear to stay in the same place, and instead looks like it's vibrating in place. How can I make it so the displayed label appears more steady?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your label's `textAlignment` property is `NSTextAlignmentCenter`, Try to set the label's `textAlignment` property to `NSTextAlignmentLeft` or `NSTextAlignmentRight`.